# Object Expected error in js file

Tags: c#, javascript, scriptmanager

i have a control which is on update panel. i want my javascript code run every time the updatePAnel is updated. i used something like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "my_script", "runFunction();", true);
```

Everything worked fine. Then i changed my code a bit in order to use js file with js code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this, GetType(), "my_script", "~\Scripts\MyScript.js");
```

But now i get Object Expected error in MyScript.js.

what can be wrong?

EDIT:

my js code:

```
var http = getHTTPObject(); // We create the HTTP Object

function checkFilesExists() {
    var links = $('.PrIcon').find('a');

    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (!checkFileExists(links[i].href)) {
            links[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
}

checkFilesExists();

function checkFileExists(handleRequest) {
    /*http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpReceiveNewPwd;*/
    /*http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');*/
    try {
        http.open('HEAD', handleRequest, false);
        http.send(null);
        return http.status == 200;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}

function getHTTPObject() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
        var obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (obj.overrideMimeType) {
            obj.overrideMimeType('application/pdf');
        }
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        try {
            var obj = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                var obj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) { }
        }
    }
    if (obj)
        return obj;
}
```

the error occurs on this line: var links = $('.PrIcon').find('a');

Comment: I guess we'll need to see the function `runFunction()` which is probably raising this error. On which line do you get this error when you look in the javascript console (F12) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your script seems to depends on some other (probably jQuery), but the `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude` renders the `<script>` tag too early in the page (before the script your's depends on is interpreted, and thus, not creating the necessary objects). A better option in this case is to use the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` method, but instead of passing the script body, you shall pass the entire `<script>` tag with your script's address:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updatePanel, updatePanel.GetType(), "a_key", "<script type='text/javascript' src='my_script.js'></script>", false);
```

Note that the last parameter, which sets the `addScriptTags` flag is set to false, allowing you to render the entire tag with the `src` attribute defined.